# Are there any alternatives to "Adjustment Curves" in Inkscape?

Tags: inkscape, image-editing

[Adjustment curves](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Kf4melsXrbM) is a very commonly used feature in graphic design.

Inkscape doesn't seem to have this feature.Even if Inkscape is a vector graphics software , this feature comes in really handy in blending vector objects with images.

Are there any workarounds to achieve this effect in Inkscape ?

Comment: Curves dont work well on a vector paradigm. In a raster graphic its easy to manipulate what you see because you can make a snapshot of the end result then manipulate that (since that is how raster layering works snapshots of result). In a vector you can not do this without exploding your graphic to millions of pieces. So either the curves of vector graphics would work unintuitively differently from rastee curves or the function would need to flatten all your art which would defeat the purpose of the function. I mean its pretty easy to do if you forego antialiasing, transparency and blendmodes

Comment: Inkscape has Extension > Color > Custom which allows curves as math expressions. Unfortunately I do not know the expression writing language nor limitations. In addition I do not believe it affects to the rendering result with blending modes nor even groups, I believe it affects only single objects. A superuser or programmer  is needed for full answer.

Comment: color_custom.py, line 7 and following say it supports the following operators:
+ (addition), - (subtraction), * (multiplication), / (division), ** (power), ^ (bitwise exclusive or), - (negative). The expression writing language is Python. The extension changes the color of objects, disregarding any blend modes. The part about ignoring group styles could be called a bug. Bug reports should go to https://inkscape.org/report . There are a couple more extensions in the 'color' category that allow you to modify color.